# Jquery only processing first function/block of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with three different snippets of jquery code, all doing different things. The problem is that when they are all on the page, only the first one works. I've changed the order, and regardless of the snippet, only the first one works. Is there an internal jquery conflict I'm missing?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

jQuery(document).ready( function() {

    $("#main-menu li").mouseenter(function() {  
        $(this).find("ul").fadeIn();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).parent().find("ul").fadeOut();
    });

    jQuery( ".text-resize a" ).textresizer({
         target: ".content",
         type: "fontSize",
         sizes: [ "12px", "16px" ],
         selectedIndex: 0
    });
    jQuery( ".text-resize a" ).textresizer({
         target: ".title",
         type: "fontSize",
         sizes: [ "11px", "16px" ],
         selectedIndex: 0
    });
    jQuery( ".text-resize a" ).textresizer({
         target: ".show-more",
         type: "fontSize",
         sizes: [ "12px", "16px" ],
         selectedIndex: 0
    });
    jQuery( ".text-resize a" ).textresizer({
         target: "#footer",
         type: "fontSize",
         sizes: [ "12px", "16px" ],
         selectedIndex: 0
    }); 
    jQuery( ".text-resize a" ).textresizer({
         target: ".copyright",
         type: "fontSize",
         sizes: [ "11px", "16px" ],
         selectedIndex: 0
    }); 

        $(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

        // enable "cross-fading" effect
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeOutSpeed: "2000",
        // start from the beginning after the last tab   
        rotate: true          
    // use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
    }).slideshow( {autoplay: true, interval:3000});

});     
</script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you loading other javascript libraries?

Comment: are you sure you can call `.textresizer` on the same element more than once?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting a javascript error? An error will stop execution of further script.

Comment: These are all the libraries I load:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.textresizer.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have not had any problems with text resizer with this usage in the past.

Comment: I checked Firebug and there are no problems, like I said, it will execute whichever code is first, just not all of them together :S

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this [textResizer plugin](http://angstrey.com/index.php/projects/jquery-text-resizer-plugin/). You really should be using `type="cssClass"` if you are going to target different sections of the page with different sizes.

```
jQuery( ".text-resize a" ).textresizer({
     target: "body",
     type: "cssClass",
     sizes: [ "size1", "size2" ],
     selectedIndex: 0
});
```

You CSS would look something like

```
body.size1 .content { font-size: 12px;}
body.size2 .content { font-size: 16px;}

body.size1 .title { font-size: 11px;}
body.size2 .title { font-size: 16px;}

body.size1 .show-more { font-size: 12px;}
body.size2 .show-more { font-size: 16px;}

body.size1 #footer { font-size: 12px;}
body.size2 #footer { font-size: 16px;}

body.size1 .copyright { font-size: 11px;}
body.size2 .copyright { font-size: 16px;}
```

It would be better to combine the CSS for the ones that are the same

```
body.size1 .title,
body.size1 .copyright { font-size: 11px;}

body.size1 .content,
body.size1 #footer,
body.size1 .show-more { font-size: 12px;}

body.size2 .content,
body.size2 .title,
body.size2 .show-more,
body.size2 #footer,
body.size2 .copyright { font-size: 16px;}
```

Comment: You're right, I should. Thank you for the help on that front! Unfortunately this doesn't affect my issue, either the resizer works, or one of the other blocks of code.